# Device Detection Issue Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, device-detection

We are running our Sitecore instance on `Sitecore 9.0.2`. Our website is not responsive website for mobile version we are using device detection. But only in IOS chrome browser device detection is not working and we are seeing desktop version header in mobile device as well.

Please share your thoughts if anyone face same or related issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you testing on real device or just simulators?

Comment: Maybe you already have, but otherwise check out this guide for setup.  https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-sitecore-device-detection.html 

Also look for any JavaScript or CSS issues that might be causing the desktop version header to appear on mobile devices in.

Answer (score 0):

Previously, we encountered a similar issue even with version 9.2 as per the requirement.

During that time, we made it by disabling the built-in Device Detection Rules and utilizing [front-end mobile detection](https://github.com/hgoebl/mobile-detect.js) with JavaScript instead.

There is a known bug: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/828414 for 9.0.1. Not exactly sure if it's working for 9.0.2.

For more detailed troubleshooting, I recommend referring to the following resource: https://bala.one/sitecore-device-detection/. This post contains information on how to verify the functionality of device detection.

If you still want to utilize Sitecore Device Detection and there are no error messages in the Sitecore logs, I suggest raising a support ticket to the Sitecore team for further assistance.

They will be able to provide you with more specific guidance or hotfix.